# Ganache not changing the accounts balance!

Tags: truffle, ganache

I am working on a smart contract and using Ganache for testing when I run

```
truffle migrate
```

the smart contract migrates to ganache successfully and the blocks are created however the balance on the account section is not changing.

it's showing a 100 balance for all accounts no matter how many transactions I complete.

why is that?

```
ganache: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*"
    },
```

Comment: Are you using the ganache graphical interface? And by migrating to ganache successfully, do you mean that you can see the contracts in the contracts section of the graphical interface?

Comment: yes, I am using ganache gui and I can see **block creating and transaction details** too but the balance is still 100. when I import the account to MetaMask then it does not show the 100 then it shows the balance remaining after a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

`truffle migrate` runs migrations on local ganache instance included within truffle itself.

To tell truffle to use `ganache-gui` you need to use

```bash
truffle migrate --network ganache
```

as you defined ganache as a network in `truffle-config.js`

Comment: tried `truffle migrate --network ganache` too same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that u have added network_id as 5777(network_id of ganache) not *